# python regex for date with words and numbers in long string

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

```
 'none; but currently has appt with new HJH PCP Rachel Salas, MD on October. 11, 2013 Other Agency Involvement: No\n')'
```

and I am trying to get "October. 11, 2013" out of it.

The comma after the 11 needs to be optional.

The code I am using is:

```
re.findall(r'(\S+)\s*\d+,*\s([2][0]\d\d|[1][9]\d\d)', raw_data[i])
```

and the output I am getting is skipping the 11:

[('October.', '2013')]

explanation of my logic:

(\S+)\s* # limit the word before the number to max 1 occurence, and avoid the full sentence. optional space between word and number

\d+,* # catch the number between the month and the year, with an optional comma

\s([2][0]\d\d|[1][9]\d\d) # catch the year after the space

I am very grateful for your help.

Comment: Remove the first capturing parentheses group and make the second one non-capturing. Or, use `re.findall(r'\S+\s*\d+,*\s(?:20|19)\d\d', s)`. Or use your regex with `re.finditer` and grab `x.group()` in a list comprehension.

Comment: Dear @WiktorStribiżew - many thanks, first option works.